# Await / axios always return pending action with redux toolkit

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm moving from Duck to redux toolkit.

Now I'll try to explain this behavior, this thing:  `= await axios` always return the ***pending*** action. Removing the `await` the api call "works", but return `undefined`.

So what I'm missing here?

```
  'movies/searchByTitle',
  async (values, thunkAPI) => {
    const API_KEY = '';
    try {
      let {movieTitle} = values;
      let page = 1;
      
      let movies = await axios
        .get(
          `//api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=${movieTitle}&api_key=${API_KEY}&include_adult=false&page=${page}`,
        )
        .then(response => {
          console.log('results: ', response);
          return response.data;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          const message =
            (error.response &&
              error.response.data &&
              error.response.data.message) ||
            error.message ||
            error.toString();
          console.log(message);
          thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error);
        });
      return movies;
    } catch (error) {
      const message =
        (error.response &&
          error.response.data &&
          error.response.data.message) ||
        error.message ||
        error.toString();
      console.log(message);
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
    }
  },
);
```

Edited: I did some changes, and now Im getting `undefined` with `fulfilled` action.

```
const API_KEY = '';

const fetchMoviesByTitle = async (title, page) => {
  const url = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=${title}&api_key=${API_KEY}&include_adult=false&page=${page}`;
  const {data} = axios.get(url);
  return await data;
};

export const searchByTitle = createAsyncThunk(
  'movies/searchByTitle',
  async (values, thunkAPI) => {
    let {movieTitle} = values;
    let page = 1;

    let data = await fetchMoviesByTitle(movieTitle, page)
      .then(results => {
        return results;
      })
      .catch(err => {
        return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(err.message);
      });
    console.log(data);
    return data;
  },
);
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Don't mix `await` with `.then()` / `.catch()`, it just makes code confusing

Answer (score 0):

you're mixing `try / catch` with `then / catch`. Most of the time, you don't do both of them at the same time. You can only choose one of them most of the time.

Here's an example with `try / catch`:

```
  'movies/searchByTitle',
  async (values, thunkAPI) => {
    const API_KEY = '';
    try {
      let {movieTitle} = values;
      let page = 1;
      
      let movies = await axios
        .get(
          `//api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=${movieTitle}&api_key=${API_KEY}&include_adult=false&page=${page}`,
        )
        console.log('results: ', movies);
      return movies;
    } catch (error) {
      const message =
        (error.response &&
          error.response.data &&
          error.response.data.message) ||
        error.message ||
        error.toString();
      console.log(message);
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
    }
  },
);
```

or here's an example with `then / catch`:

```
'movies/searchByTitle',
  async (values, thunkAPI) => {
    const API_KEY = '';
    return axios
        .get(
          `//api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=${movieTitle}&api_key=${API_KEY}&include_adult=false&page=${page}`,
        )
.then(response => {
          console.log('results: ', response);
          return response.data;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          const message =
            (error.response &&
              error.response.data &&
              error.response.data.message) ||
            error.message ||
            error.toString();
          console.log(message);
          return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error);
        });
  },
);
```